# Need a decent book covering Grassmannians and surrounding theory

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

As the title states, I'm looking for a decent book (advanced undergraduate, or graduate level) covering Grassmannians and surrounding theory.

It seems to be that Grassmannians are hiding in a great deal of different mathematical topics, so I'm looking for something that can give me a decent overview of them, their topology, and other intricacies.

Suggestions?